# Check .htaccess If file or folder exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Im looking for a way to set some settings for my script
I want any entered address in URL bar check by .htaccess , If the text entered after ( LIKE domain.com/foldername) then check and folder exist goes to folder
If text was not similar to any folder in root , then check it for file and at the end goes to specific file
so let me explain it with example in .htaccess :

```
If ( text = folder )
   goes to folder
elseif( text == file )
   goes to file.php
else
   goes to sample.php?text
```

UPDATE : 
I have tickets.php and theme folder on root , I want If the url was domain.com/theme then goes to folder named theme and/or if domain.com/tickets goes to ticket.php

Comment: This is a typical use case for mod_rewrite. Clarify please though - if the requested URL is `/file` do you want to check for the existence of `/file.php`, or do you expect that the user would have submitted `/file.php` as the request URL?

Comment: here are some interesting reading that mgiht help you http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/ and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I need the htaccess first check if folder exit goes to folder and If folder does not exist check it for files in root and if the file not exist to so goes to sample.php

Comment: Which stupid coder rate this question Negative ? Show me yourself damn you or answer here If you think you know it :|

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On

# If ( text = folder )
RewriteRule ^folder/?$ - [L]

# if( text == file.php )
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ - [L]

# else
RewriteRule !^sample\.php /sample.php?text [L]
```

Or if you mean *any* file or folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If ( text = folder )
# if( text == file.php )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# else
RewriteRule !^sample\.php /sample.php?text [L]
```

Comment: Thanks , but not exactly like this , I want to check folder and file without extension , I mean check text is similar to folder or file without .php

Comment: Both of them did not work , I have tickets.php and theme folder on root , I want If the url was domain.com/theme then goes to theme and if domain.com/tickets goes to ticket.php

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common pattern.

This rule will only fire if the path is not a folder or a file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sample.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: I just put this code , but I got "server error" message :(

Comment: I think I made error in the syntax. I think the one works. I don't have a live example so I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks but still did not work , check main question : I have tickets.php and theme folder on root , I want If the url was domain.com/theme then goes to folder named theme and/or if domain.com/tickets goes to ticket.php

Comment: Add another rule for `/tickets` then.

Comment: tickets is a sample , I want htaccess do it for all files in root , contact.php , support.php etc ...

Comment: So `/contacts` to `/contact.php` and `/supports` to `/support.php`? Just add rules for all of them. Or make one rule to handle them all. Don't over-complicate things.